# Boxy Shading in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting, shadows

I'm making a mountain model (in cycles render), but for some reason when I get close to the mountain the shading looks boxy instead of smooth.

[image]

I have smooth shading on, and I put a subdivision surface modifier on, but it still looks boxy when I get close up.  How to fix this?

Comment: how close is your camera going to be? Real rocks are not all rounded and smooth - having a few sharp edges may actually make it look better. (But if the screenshot is showing your entire camera angle, then you would want to add more detail to it).

Comment: As a first step, view and check the consistency of the normals in your geometry -  eliminate any flipped faces (edit faces > Ctrl-N) - look out for duplicated faces,vertices ..

Comment: Thanks for that link, at least now I know what it's called, it's called the "terminator problem."  But I still don't know how to fix it. And adding more vertices simply makes the shadows look like a bunch of smaller squares.